# Can I Choose the Install Location of 'Path of Exile'?

Tags: path-of-exile

I'd like to install *Path of Exile* to an external hard drive, since I'll never be able to download it at home.

But when I run the launcher, it starts 'Allocating Space', which leads me to believe it already knows where it's going to download and install the game to.

Is there a way I can force it to install to a certain location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though this thread is very old, I'd like to give an updated answer because this thread is ranked #1 on Google.

In the current installer, the setting is hidden. When you first open it, before accepting the EULA and clicking `Install`, there is an `Options` button next to `Install`. This is where you can find the settings now.

Answer (score 3):

You clicked 'Next Next Next' too much without reading what was going on when running the installer:

[image]

If you've already got to the 'Allocate Space' stage, you will need to cancel out of it, uninstall whatever has already been downloaded, and then run the installer again.

Comment: It's the third screen after running `PathOfExileInstaller.msi` from the Path of Exile website, just after accepting the license. If you didn't see this screen then you're probably not using the installer off their website. If this is the case, you should be able to copy whatever you've got to the location you'd like the game downloading to and run it from there.

Comment: I thought you were talking about this showing up after running the *client*.  I did this for the installer I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't appear to have worked.  There's a folder in the place I wanted it which is clearly from my school network where I downloaded it (judging by the name) and it follows this structure: *algshare* > *home* > *My Documents* > *My Games* > *Path of Exile* but there's nothing in the final folder.

Comment: Which part didn't work?

Comment: Weird, have you ensured that you've removed the game from Programs & Features before trying to reinstall it? I have my copy installed on D: so I know it works

Comment: It's not in this computer's programs and features either.  Hmm.  I'm going to try it again from the beginning, I didn't install it all in one go that time.  **Edit:** Wait a minute, when I go to delete it, it says that it's deleting 5.51 GB.  The hell is going on here?

Comment: The "Allocating Space" phase creates a data container the size of the data file it is going to download.

Comment: In windows explorer though, the new folder contained 0 bytes.  Anyway, I'll comment again once it finishes again, I removed everything and started over from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that for me, simply dragging and dropping the pre-install folder to different place worked just fine.